# Unable to play certain games at all

Tags: technical-issues

For a long time now I've been having issues with certain games (Actually quite a lot of games) with this same recurring issue:

Whenever I try play a game it will open fine with absolutely no errors at all but when it goes into fullscreen it just has a black screen then minimizes shortly after. Every time I try maximize it it just minimizes again after a short delay. Whenever I do maximize it, I can hear the sound of any background music might be playing or any noises etc.

Some of these are Steam games and others are Origin games. I have tried deleting the Steam `appcache` and it did work for some games but it seems I will have to delete it and restart my computer whenever I want to play a game and even still that only works *sometimes*.

Computer specs that may help:

- My graphics driver is up to date
- My graphics card is a Nvidia Geforce GTX 760

(I will add any extra details if you request them)

Comment: update your graphics card drivers

Comment: are you using multiple monitors?

Comment: My graphics drivers are up to date already and I only have 1 monitor.

Comment: Could you name at least some of the games?

Comment: Some of the games are:
The entire C&C series,
Payday 2,
The entire Supreme Comamnder series,
The Sims 3. To name a few.

Comment: Have you tried updating adobe reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue as there was one thing I hadn't tried, which was too reinstall the drivers. By reinstalling my drivers all the games that previously didn't work now do.

Thank you for all those who tried to help me with this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your graphic cards driver and DirectX components are up to date.

Some software may interfere on the fullscreen part of a game. Software like teamviewer, displayfusion, or VNC can interfere when a game try to hook fullscreen. Try to shutdown a few running program and see if it works.

Comment: please don't use unnecessary code ticks. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/using-code-ticks-for-technical-term-highlighting-considered-harmful

Comment: I've checked and all my drivers and DirectX componenets are up to date (excluding any beta drivers which I may try when I have the chance). As for programs I always have the bare minimum open and other fullscreen games work. I don't see any conflicts with the programs I currently have running either.

Comment: What OS are you using ?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate